# Update plot in shiny with plotlyproxy when source plot hasn't rendered yet

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I would like to update a plot in shiny using plotlyproxy based on an input value, where the plot is in a tab that isn't the first tab, and therefore may not have been rendered yet when the user changes the input value.

Currently, if the user hasn't clicked on the tab containing the plot at all before they change the input value, when they view the plot tab the plot does not update. i.e. the tab with the plot needs to be viewed at least once before the plot will start to respond to changes in the input value.

This is a minimal example:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(data.table)

trace_1 <- rnorm(100, mean = 5)
trace_2 <- rnorm(100, mean = 0)
trace_3 <- rnorm(100, mean = -5)
x <- c(1:100)

data <- data.table(x, trace_1, trace_2, trace_3)

ui <- fluidPage(
  radioGroupButtons("tracenum", label = "Trace number to change marker colour", choices = 1:3, selected = NULL),
  tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
              tabPanel("First tab", textOutput("text")),
              tabPanel("Second tab", plotlyOutput("plot"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
  output$text <- renderText({
    paste("Trace number", input$tracenum, "has been selected")
  })
 
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~trace_1, name = 'trace 1', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers')
    fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~trace_2, name = 'trace 2', mode = 'lines+markers')
    fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~trace_3, name = 'trace 3', mode = 'lines+markers')
    fig
  })
 
  observeEvent(input$tracenum, {
   
    if (!is.na(input$tracenum)) {
      data[, updatevar := get(paste0("trace_", input$tracenum))]
      plotlyProxy("plot", session) %>%
        plotlyProxyInvoke("addTraces", list(x = c(data$x, data$x),
                                            y = c(data$updatevar, data$updatevar),
                                            type = "scatter", mode = "markers",
                                            marker = list(color = "black")))
    }
   
  })
   
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If a user selects to update trace 2 when they are first viewing the first tab (i.e. they haven’t clicked on the second tab at all and the plot has not rendered yet), I would like that selection to have an effect when they click on the second tab that contains the plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to set `suspendWhenHidden = FALSE` via `outputOptions()`:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(data.table)

trace_1 <- rnorm(100, mean = 5)
trace_2 <- rnorm(100, mean = 0)
trace_3 <- rnorm(100, mean = -5)
x <- c(1:100)

data <- data.table(x, trace_1, trace_2, trace_3)

ui <- fluidPage(
  radioGroupButtons("tracenum", label = "Trace number to change marker colour", choices = 1:3, selected = NULL),
  tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
              tabPanel("First tab", textOutput("text")),
              tabPanel("Second tab", plotlyOutput("plot"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$text <- renderText({
    paste("Trace number", input$tracenum, "has been selected")
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~trace_1, name = 'trace 1', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers')
    fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~trace_2, name = 'trace 2', mode = 'lines+markers')
    fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~trace_3, name = 'trace 3', mode = 'lines+markers')
    fig
  })
  
  outputOptions(output, "plot", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$tracenum, {
    if (!is.na(input$tracenum)) {
      data[, updatevar := get(paste0("trace_", input$tracenum))]
      plotlyProxy("plot", session) %>%
        plotlyProxyInvoke("addTraces", list(x = c(data$x, data$x),
                                            y = c(data$updatevar, data$updatevar),
                                            type = "scatter", mode = "markers",
                                            marker = list(color = "black")))
    }
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```